# What is the best way to benchmark custom components in a spaCy pipeline?

Tags: python, spacy

I've recently refactored some of the components in my spaCy pipeline, and as a result, the pipeline runs 7x slower than it did previous to the refactor. I'm not sure which component in my spaCy pipeline is the culprit of the slowdown, and can't figure out how to gain some transparency on how long it takes text to flow through each component. If I knew which component was causing the slowdown, it would be much simpler to identify the offending code.

I've thought about adding a custom extension to each Doc object, and having each pipeline component add the amount of time it took to process through, but that seems like it might be problematic.

Are there any spaCy-recommended methods to do so, or has anyone else solved this problem in a clever way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good question and the extension attribute idea is actually very clever! The only downside is that you'd have to add debugging code to all of your existing components (which also works less well if they're third-party code). But if you know that the offending code is part of your codebase, this shouldn't be a problem.

Another option would be to wrap each pipeline component in a function that logs the timestamp and whatever else you need and returns `pipe(doc)`. You can then overwrite `nlp.pipeline` with those wrapped components:

```py
def wrap_pipe(name, pipe):
    def wrapped(doc):
        print(f"Started '{name}'", datetime.datetime.now())
        return pipe(doc)
    return wrapped

def debug_wrap_pipeline(nlp):
    nlp.pipeline = [(name, wrap_pipe(name, pipe)) for name, pipe in nlp.pipeline]
    return nlp

debug_nlp = debug_wrap_pipeline(nlp)
```

However, the downside here is that you'd also need to wrap each component's `.pipe` method (if available) so you can run and debug `nlp.pipe` under the same conditions. If you're benchmarking, you often want to do this at a larger scale and process a stream of texts with `nlp.pipe`.

To avoid this, a slightly more verbose option could be to add a "debug component" before each existing component in the pipeline. Basically, something like this:

```py
def make_debug_component(name):
    def debug_component(doc):
        print(f"Before '{name}'", datetime.datetime.now())
        return doc
    return debug_component

def debug_wrap_pipeline(nlp):
    pipeline = list(nlp.pipeline)  # we don't want to modify this while we're looping over it
    for name, pipe in pipeline:
        debug_component = make_debug_component(name)
        nlp.add_pipe(debug_component, before=name, name=f"debug_{name}")
    return nlp
```

Disclaimer: I only just hacked those ideas together and haven't tested them extensively yet. But they did seem to work. If you end up exploring this, I'd be very curious to hear what worked best. It might also be a feature that spaCy could ship with out-of-the-box, and it'd pair well with the proposed [static analysis for pipeline components](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/3943).

Also, just to add for completeness: When debugging text processing pipelines like this, always benchmark things on a larger scale with a single corpus that you process *once* (rather than looping over a single example 1000 times or something like that). There are caching effects (both within spaCy, but also the CPU), differences in memory allocation and so on that can all have an impact and make the small-scale tests less reliable. Of course, in a scenario like this where you're experiencing drastic differences, even processing a single text can probably give you enough clues and everything you need to debug your code further.

Comment: I really like both of these approaches. I implemented your second solution with `nlp.pipe`, using `batch_size=1` to ensure timestamps were sequential, and using `datetime.datetime.now().timestamp()` in order to log epoch times that are more sane to then run analyses on. It turns out that my `EntityRuler` component is taking, on average, 29x as long as my second slowest component and 2300x as long as my quickest. At least I know where to start looking now :)